# 'startBlock' and 'endBlock' appear to be a common theme for distributing tokens, but I'm not seeing where or how they're specified

Tags: solidity, transactions, contract-design

I was looking at [BAT's token contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x0d8775f648430679a709e98d2b0cb6250d2887ef) and the transactions being rejected, so I wondered how you scheduled these distributions. That led me to [First Blood's](https://etherscan.io/address/0xaf30d2a7e90d7dc361c8c4585e9bb7d2f6f15bc7#code) sale contract. The first mention of 'startBlock' that I saw was on line 145.

```
uint public startBlock; //crowdsale start block (set in constructor)

uint public endBlock; //crowdsale end block (set in constructor)
```

The last mention of either (outside of some comparison) is here:

```
function FirstBloodToken(address founderInput, address signerInput, uint startBlockInput, uint endBlockInput) {

    founder = founderInput;
    signer = signerInput;
    startBlock = startBlockInput;
    endBlock = endBlockInput;
}
```

...what exactly am I missing here? I haven't exactly poured over this yet, though I feel like this should be fairly obvious and yet I'm not seeing which block this contract started accepting transactions at.

Answer (score 1):

The `startBlock` and `endBlock` are passed to contract through a constructor. So you should query them from the contract state and as they are public variables you should be able to use `call` to query both the variables from the public network without costing any ether. The following gives an idea as to how to interact with contract using call https://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/content/interacting_contract.html